# how to sum the column values and update these sum values in another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and values like this, I want the output as shown in the below figure, First i need to order by the area and then i have to summation the mhs_count based on the area ordering and then i need to update it in total_sum last corresponding row-side as total_sum as shown in the figure

```
create table AreaSummary1( area varchar(250),mhs_count int, total_sum int) 

insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',1)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',2)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',3)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',4)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',5)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',6)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',7)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',8)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',9)
```

[image]

Comment: You do this with a reporting tool, not a query.

Comment: can you be more specific with examples

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR please find posted query is it useful to your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Row_number and aggregate functions.

```
SELECT area
       ,mhs_count
       ,CASE WHEN RN<(MAX(RN) OVER(PARTITION BY AREA)) THEN 0 ELSE TOT END AS total_sum
FROM 
(SELECT area,mhs_count,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AREA ORDER BY AREA) RN,sum(mhs_count) over(partition by area) TOT
FROM AreaSummary1) X
```

Comment: wow, it helped a lot man, but instead of select, can you show it by writing update statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can get sum of col mhs_count like:

```
SELECT SUM(mhs_count) AS Totalcount FROM yourTableName WHERE area='AAA'

//Output : 12
```

And similarly for other areas as well.

PS: If you are trying to store a calculated value in a table, let me tell you that it is not a good practice, you must always calculate values before showing it on on front end.

This will always return updated values.

Comment: ya i got it, but i need these values to be particularly placed in the corresponding row as i shown in the figure

Comment: For that you can execute query and get sum in a variable and then put that variable in some place holder like table <td>

Comment: and i don't want to name out the values manually like 'AAA' or 'BBB', i want it to holds good for all values in a single shot

Comment: can you be more specific with examples?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean update the total_sum to the line that has maxium mhs_count

```
update a set a.total_sum=b.total_sum from AreaSummary1 as a
inner join (select a1.area, sum(a1.mhs_count) as total_sum,max(a1.mhs_count) as max_mhs from AreaSummary1 as a1 group by a1.area) as b
on a.area=b.area and a.mhs_count=b.max_mhs

select * from AreaSummary1 order by area,mhs_count
```

```
area    mhs_count   total_sum
AAA 1   NULL
AAA 4   NULL
AAA 7   12
BBB 2   NULL
BBB 5   NULL
BBB 8   15
CCC 3   NULL
CCC 6   NULL
CCC 9   18
```

**By physical address:**

This is a sample order by address(using %%lockres%%)
If you want to change the sort column, just change the ORDER BY in ROW_NUMBER

```
CREATE table AreaSummary1( area varchar(250),mhs_count int, total_sum int) 

insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',1)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',8) --changed the store sequence
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',3)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',4)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',5)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',6)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('AAA',7)
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('BBB',2) ---changed the sequence
insert into AreaSummary1(area,mhs_count) values ('CCC',9)

update a set a.total_sum=aa.total_sum 
--SELECT * 
FROM AreaSummary1 as a
CROSS apply ( SELECT SUM(b.mhs_count) AS total_sum,MAX(b.locid) AS locid FROM (
SELECT a1.mhs_count ,CASE WHEN COUNT(0)OVER()=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY a1.%%lockres%%) THEN   (a1.%%lockres%%) ELSE '' END  AS locid
from AreaSummary1 as a1 WHERE  a1.area=a.area) as b
) aa
WHERE aa.locid= a.%%lockres%%

select area,mhs_count,ISNULL(LTRIM(total_sum),'') AS total_sum from AreaSummary1 order by area,%%lockres%%
```

```
area    mhs_count   total_sum
AAA 1   
AAA 4   
AAA 7   12
BBB 8   
BBB 5   
BBB 2   15
CCC 3   
CCC 6   
CCC 9   18
```

Comment: i don't want to be in max_mhs, just i want to place in that particular place, it wont work for other tables

Comment: i mean there could be variable values for mhs_count's

Comment: is thereany last function which helps me to place the value?

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR I am still no idea about the rule which line should be placed the total. by sequence?by specify column value?

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR if other table has different data you can update the line refer %%lockres%% get the data address that should be update.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR I had modified my answer，Can you try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
into #t
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY area ORDER BY area DESC) AS Seq
,*
FROM #AreaSummary1
)t


select x.area
    ,x.mhs_count
    ,case when convert(varchar(10),x.total_sum) = 0 then ''
    else x.total_sum end as total_sum
from(
select t.area
    ,t.mhs_count
    ,case when t.Seq = c.lastMember then b.total_sum
        else '' end as total_sum
from #t t
left outer join (select area        
                ,sum(mhs_count) as total_sum
            from #t
            group by area) b on b.area = t.area
left outer join (select area
                ,max(Seq) as lastMember
            from #t
            group by area) c on c.area = t.area
) x
```

Comment: Sorry, I've missed part of the code - Seq is derived column in order to retrieve last row in the area group.

Comment: ok. it works, but can you provide the code in update statement?

Comment: or can you do it without temp table, i.e direct updation?

Answer (score 0):

using Row_number we can achieve this

```
Select area,
mhs_count,
CASE WHEN RNN = 3 then RN ELSE NULL END Total_Sum 
from 
(
select 
        area,
        mhs_count,
        SUM(mhs_count)OVER(PARTITION BY area)RN,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY area ORDER BY area)RNN 
    from AreaSummary1
)T
```

Comment: i want max(RNN) in place of 3, can you alter it please